# Using a link in XSL Files

Tags: xslt, hyperlink

I am completely new to XML so hopefully my explanations will make sense..

I am using an XSL file with 2 sections of HTML text, reading from 2 templates set up within the file.

The first text and associated template is a table, and I have set up a link within that. I want the link to then point to a picture that is part of the 2nd HTML text/template.

The link in the table is setup in that it appears as a link, underlined, etc. However it doesnt go anywhere when clicked.

The second section works fine on it's own, eg, pictures and text appears.

But what I cant figure out is how to actually get the link to work. I've tried numerous things but nothing has worked so far. And I-m not sure whether I am very close and just perhaps need to alter a line of code. Or whether I need to be doing something very different. Also, there are no error messages, and everything displays well, it's just the link itself that doesnt work.

```
 <xsl:template match="portion">
  <tr>
 <td valign="top"><xsl:value-of select="food-description"/></td>
 <td valign="top"><xsl:value-of select="food-number"/></td>
 <!--the following is the link text-->  
 <td valign="top"><a><xsl:attribute name="href">#<xsl:value-of select="portion-     photo/@file"/></xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:value-of select="portion-photo/@file"/></a><br/>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="portion-photo">
 <!--I know that this is the code that is not correct, however, believe it should      be something similar-->  
 <a><xsl:attribute name="portion-photo"><xsl:value-of select="./@file"/></xsl:attribute></a>  

 <p><xsl:value-of select="../food-description"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="./@file"/></p>

 <img>
   <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="./@file"/></xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="ceiling(./@w div v2)"/></xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="height"><xsl:value-of select="ceiling(./@h div 2)"/></xsl:attribute>
  </img>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is this your original XSLT script? If so, you might want to remove the whitespace between _portion-_ and _photo_ in the `select`attribute of the third `xsl:value-of`. BTW, you can directly add attribute values without using `xsl:attribute`. Just put the XPath expressions in curly braces: `<a href="#{portion-photo/@file}"/>`

Comment: You have forgotten to provide the source XML  -- please edit the question and do so. Also, please specify the exact wanted result for the XML you provide.

Comment: Yes I created it if that's what you are asking using various code I have seen/read about. the whitespace is only there because of the way I copied it into here. it's not in the original. re> <a href="#{portion-photo/@file}"/> gives me error messages. Does changing/adding that make any difference to getting the links to work.

Comment: @Dimitre. Here's an extract. <portion>
  <food-description>Rice </food-description>
  <food-number>1</food-number>
  <portion-photo file="01.jpg"/>
 </portion>

Comment: @KGreen: No, not portion but a complete (and small) XML document. And not in a comment -- please edit the question and provide the important missing data there -- this can also be an opportunity to correct currently known typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work. Just add the missing *name* attribute to the anchor element:

```
<xsl:template match="portion">
  ...
  <a href="#{portion-photo/@file}">
    <xsl:value-of select="portion-photo/@file"/>
  </a>
  ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="portion-photo">
  <a name="{@file}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@file"/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

However, you have to ensure that `@file` evaluates to a valid anchor name. If the values of all *file* attributes are unique, you could also create save IDs with `generate-id()`:

```
<xsl:template match="portion">
  ...
  <a href="#{generate-id(portion-photo)}">
    <xsl:value-of select="portion-photo/@file"/>
  </a>
  ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="portion-photo">
  <a name="{generate-id()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@file"/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```